# JVM thread hangs occasionally

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

I'm trouble shooting a delay issue in the system, and I notice that in the same thread it has 10s delay in between the logs, and it happens once only.
from the logs i can see activities from other thread, so the JVM was not hanging.
and I don't see long GC pause in the gc log, can anyone suggest how to trouble shoot this issue

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000); //pull data from kafka
for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
  logger.debug("Record: offset = "+ record.offset() + ", key = "+record.key()+", value = " + 
  record.value()); //record.value is just a string
  V4Event event = gson.fromJson(record.value(), V4Event.class);
  MDC.put("eventId",event.getId());
  logger.info("Event id {}", event.getId());
}
```

2020-01-06 **10:36:00,284** DEBUG [pool-23-thread-1] c.c.s.m.c.KafkaFirehoseEventConsumerService - PtiE5o - [KafkaFirehoseEventConsumerService.java:140] Record: offset = 189.......

2020-01-06 **10:36:10,770** INFO [pool-23-thread-1] c.c.s.m.c.KafkaFirehoseEventConsumerService - DalD0U - [KafkaFirehoseEventConsumerService.java:143] Event id DalD0U

GC logs i can't see significant GC pause

```
2020-01-06T10:20:13.605-0500: 116355.718: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1036431K->10463K(1037312K)] 2034196K->1008524K(3134464K), 0.0176151 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2020-01-06T10:25:00.737-0500: 116642.851: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1036511K->10063K(1037312K)] 2034572K->1008692K(3134464K), 0.0152703 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2020-01-06T10:30:09.741-0500: 116951.854: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1036111K->10030K(1037312K)] 2034740K->1008787K(3134464K), 0.0287083 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
2020-01-06T10:34:09.669-0500: 117191.783: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1036078K->10208K(1037312K)] 2034835K->1009029K(3134464K), 0.0146808 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2020-01-06T10:40:05.744-0500: 117547.858: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1036256K->10336K(1037312K)] 2035077K->1009380K(3134464K), 0.0164680 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2020-01-06T10:44:58.536-0500: 117840.649: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 1036384K->10754K(1037312K)] 2035428K->1009938K(3134464K), 0.0198571 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

heap info

```
Attaching to process ID 10113, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.181-b25

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 8 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 100
   MaxHeapSize              = 3221225472 (3072.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)
```

Comment: What is MDC here?

Comment: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html